# Password protect beta website in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to find out how to password protect a website that is hosted in Azure.

This is a beta website and I want to protect it from unauthorized users before it is deployed.

I would like it so that any visitors are immediately prompted for a password before they continue on to the website.

Can this be done with an Azure website?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you achieve this for your local box? The question is far from Azure specific!

Comment: Thanks for the constructive help astaykov! Very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net web application? Activate Forms Authentication and place username and password in web.config  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da0adyye(v=vs.100).aspx
IMHO: use passwords in web.config ONLY for debug/testing.

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio. The website will already use Forms Authentication for certain area's, I wanted to apply it to the whole site for the Beta version of the site. I am not sure if the fact we will be using forms authentication already will be an issue, but I will look into this further. Thanks again.